# SQL Server CTE left outer join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, common-table-expression

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2008, `customertest` with columns customer id (`cid`) and it's boss id (`upid`), and `conftest` with `cid`, `confname`, `confvalue`

customertest schema and data:

[image]

conftest schema and data:

[image]

I want to know how to design a CTE that if `cid` in `conftest` doesn't have that `confname`'s `confvalue`, it will keep searching `upid` and till find a upper line which have `confname` and `confvalue`.

For example , I want to get value of 100 if I search for cid=4 (this is normal case). And I want to get value of 200 if I search for cid=7 or 8.

And if cid7 and cid8 have child node , it will all return 200 (of cid5) if I search using this CTE.

I don't have a clue how to do this , I think maybe can use CTE and some left outer join, please give me some example ?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please explain "And if cid7 and cid8 have child node , it will all return 200 (of cid5)". Which values do you expect here? Maybe visualize the expected results with child node and without it.

Comment: _And I want to get value of 200 if I search for cid=7 or 8._ Please axplain why 200 instead of any value? according to what? and please add sample data as formatted text instead of images.

Comment: @Sami cid 7 and 8 have upid 5 which match the row with cid 5 and value 200 in conftest.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

If it's unknown how many levels there are in the hierarchy?

Then such challenge is often done via a Recursive CTE.

**Example Snippet:**

```
--
-- Using table variables for testing reasons
--
declare @customertest table (cid int primary key, upid int);
declare @conftest table (cid int, confname varchar(6) default 'budget', confvalue int);
--
-- Sample data
--
insert into @customertest (cid, upid) values 
(1,0), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,2), (6,3), 
(7,5), (8,5), (9,8), (10,9);
insert into @conftest (cid, confvalue) values 
(1,1000), (2,700), (3,300), (4,100), (5,200), (6,300);

-- The customer that has his own budget, or not.
declare @customerID int = 10;

;with RCTE AS 
(
  --
  -- the recursive CTE starts from here. The seed records, as one could call it.
  --
  select cup.cid as orig_cid, 0 as lvl, cup.cid, cup.upid, budget.confvalue
  from @customertest as cup
  left join @conftest budget on (budget.cid = cup.cid and budget.confname = 'budget')
  where cup.cid = @customerID -- This is where we limit on the customer

  union all

  --
  -- This is where the Recursive CTE loops till it finds nothing new
  --
  select RCTE.orig_cid, RCTE.lvl+1, cup.cid, cup.upid, budget.confvalue
  from RCTE
  join @customertest as cup on (cup.cid = RCTE.upid)
  outer apply (select b.confvalue from @conftest b where b.cid = cup.cid and b.confname = 'budget') as budget
  where RCTE.confvalue is null -- Loop till a budget is found
)
select 
 orig_cid as cid, 
 confvalue
from RCTE
where confvalue is not null;
```

Result :

```
cid confvalue
--- ---------
 10       200
```

Btw, the Recursive CTE uses the OUTER APPLY because MS SQL Server doesn't allow a LEFT OUTER JOIN to be used there.

And if it's certain that there's maximum 1 level depth for the upid with a budget?
Then just simple left joins and a coalesce would do.

For example:

```
select cup.cid, coalesce(cBudget.confvalue, upBudget.confvalue) as confvalue
from @customertest as cup
left join @conftest cBudget on (cBudget.cid = cup.cid and cBudget.confname = 'budget')
left join @conftest upBudget on (upBudget.cid = cup.upid and upBudget.confname = 'budget')
where cup.cid = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are looking for a `CTE` to do that, from what I understand:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerTest(
    CID INT,
    UPID INT
    );
CREATE TABLE ConfTest(
    CID INT,
    ConfName VARCHAR(45),
    ConfValue INT
    );

INSERT INTO CustomerTest VALUES
(1, 0),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 2),
(6, 3),
(7, 5),
(8, 5);

INSERT INTO ConfTest VALUES
(1, 'Budget', 1000),
(2, 'Budget', 700),
(3, 'Budget', 300),
(4, 'Budget', 100),
(5, 'Budget', 200),
(6, 'Budget', 300);

SELECT MAX(CNT.CID) AS CID,
       CNT.ConfName,
       MIN(CNT.ConfValue) AS ConfValue
FROM ConfTest CNT INNER JOIN CustomerTest CMT ON CMT.CID = CNT.CID
                                              OR CMT.UPID = CNT.CID
WHERE  CMT.CID = 7 -- You can test for values (8, 4) or any value you want :)
GROUP BY
       CNT.ConfName;
```