# Adding Left Outer Join to recursive statement causing syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to revise a CTE recursive statement by adding a Left Outer Join to another table, but I am now getting an error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'".  Before joining the PartOperations table I had no errors and the code ran correctly.

My code:

```
    WITH MyData AS (
                  (SELECT aa.imaMethodID,
                          aa.uimaItemNumber,
                          aa.imaPartID,
                          aa.impShortDescription,
                          aa.imaQuantityPerParent,
                          aa.imrInventoryUnitOfMeasure,
                          aa.uimpManufacturer,
                          aa.uimpManufacturePartNo,
                          aa.imaLevel,
                          aa.imaMethodAssemblyID,
                          aa.imaParentAssemblyID,
                          aa.uimpModPart,
                          1 AS BOMLevel,
                          CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(aa.uimaItemNumber)) AS varchar(250)) AS LevelPath,
                          CAST(RIGHT('00000'+LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(aa.uimaItemNumber, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(aa.uimaItemNumber, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''), ''))), 5) +RIGHT('00000'+LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(aa.uimaItemNumber, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''))), 5) AS varchar(250)) AS LevelPathPadded
                   FROM M1_HB.dbo.AssemblyMaterialCombo
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN M1_HB.dbo.PartOperations ON AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodID = PartOperations.imoMethodID
                   AND AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodAssemblyID = PartOperations.imoMethodAssemblyID) AS aa
                WHERE ((aa.imaMethodRevisionID='')
                       AND (aa.imaParentAssemblyID = 0)
                       AND (aa.imaMethodID='1BC10200')
                       AND (aa.imaPartID NOT LIKE 'ZBL%'))
                UNION ALL
                  (SELECT ab.imaMethodID,
                          ab.uimaItemNumber,
                          ab.imaPartID,
                          ab.impShortDescription,
                          ab.imaQuantityPerParent,
                          ab.imrInventoryUnitOfMeasure,
                          ab.uimpManufacturer,
                          ab.uimpManufacturePartNo,
                          ab.imaLevel,
                          ab.imaMethodAssemblyID,
                          ab.imaParentAssemblyID,
                          ab.uimpModPart,
                          BOMLevel+1,
                          CAST(LevelPath + '| ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ab.uimaItemNumber)) AS varchar(250)) AS LevelPath,
                          CAST(LevelPathPadded + '| ' +RIGHT('00000'+LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(ab.uimaItemNumber, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ab.uimaItemNumber, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''), ''))), 5) +RIGHT('00000'+LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ab.uimaItemNumber, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''))), 5) AS varchar(250)) AS LevelPathPadded
                   FROM M1_HB.dbo.AssemblyMaterialCombo
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN M1_HB.dbo.PartOperations ON AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodID = PartOperations.imoMethodID
                   AND AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodAssemblyID = PartOperations.imoMethodAssemblyID) AS ab
                INNER JOIN MyData s ON ab.imaMethodID = s.imaPartID
                AND ('| ' + s.LevelPath + '| ' NOT LIKE '%|' + Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(ab.uimaItemNumber))AS varchar(250))+ '|%')
                WHERE ab.imaMethodRevisionID=''
                  AND ab.imaParentAssemblyID = 0
                  AND ab.imaPartID NOT LIKE 'ZBL%' )
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM MyData OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

My error occurs after adding the Left Outer Join to the PartOperations table here at the 'As aa':

```
FROM M1_HB.dbo.AssemblyMaterialCombo
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN M1_HB.dbo.PartOperations ON AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodID = PartOperations.imoMethodID
                   AND AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodAssemblyID = PartOperations.imoMethodAssemblyID) AS aa
```

it also occurs in the same section within the Union'ed part.

I found out that you can't have Left Outer Join in recursive CTE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

but then I found you should be able to use OUTER APPLY...[SQL Server CTE left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572575/sql-server-cte-left-outer-join?rq=1)

... and I've trying to apply it, but I can't seem to get it.

I am getting error:

```
No column name was specified for column 13 of 'MyData'
No column name was specified for column 14 of 'MyData'
No column name was specified for column 15 of 'MyData'
Invalid column name 'LevelPath'
Invalid column name 'BOMLevel'
Invalid column name 'LevelPathPadded'
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

This is my code now.

```
    WITH MyData AS (
                  SELECT aa.imaMethodID,
                          aa.uimaItemNumber,
                          aa.imaPartID,
                          aa.impShortDescription,
                          aa.imaQuantityPerParent,
                          aa.imrInventoryUnitOfMeasure,
                          aa.uimpManufacturer,
                          aa.uimpManufacturePartNo,
                          aa.imaLevel,
                          aa.imaMethodAssemblyID,
                          aa.imaParentAssemblyID,
                          aa.uimpModPart,
                          1 AS BOMLevel,
                          CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(aa.uimaItemNumber)) AS varchar(250)) AS LevelPath,
                          CAST(………) AS LevelPathPadded
                   FROM M1_HB.dbo.AssemblyMaterialCombo aa
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN M1_HB.dbo.PartOperations ba ON aa.imaMethodID = ba.imoMethodID
                   AND aa.imaMethodAssemblyID = ba.imoMethodAssemblyID
                WHERE ((aa.imaMethodRevisionID='')
                       AND (aa.imaParentAssemblyID = 0)
                       AND (aa.imaMethodID='1BC10200')
                       AND (aa.imaPartID NOT LIKE 'ZBL%'))
                UNION ALL
                  SELECT ab.imaMethodID,
                          ab.uimaItemNumber,
                          ab.imaPartID,
                          ab.impShortDescription,
                          ab.imaQuantityPerParent,
                          ab.imrInventoryUnitOfMeasure,
                          ab.uimpManufacturer,
                          ab.uimpManufacturePartNo,
                          ab.imaLevel,
                          ab.imaMethodAssemblyID,
                          ab.imaParentAssemblyID,
                          ab.uimpModPart,
                          BOMLevel+1,
                          CAST(LevelPath + '| ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ab.uimaItemNumber)) AS varchar(250)) AS LevelPath,
                          CAST(LevelPathPadded + ……) AS LevelPathPadded
                   FROM M1_HB.dbo.AssemblyMaterialCombo ab
                INNER JOIN MyData s ON ab.imaMethodID = s.imaPartID
                AND ('| ' + s.LevelPath + '| ' NOT LIKE '%|' + Cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(ab.uimaItemNumber))AS varchar(250))+ '|%')

Outer Apply(select bb.imoMethodOperationID from M1_HB.dbo.PartOperations bb Where s.imaMethodID = bb.imoMethodID AND s.imaMethodAssemblyID = bb.imoMethodAssemblyID AND ab.imaMethodRevisionID='' AND ab.imaParentAssemblyID = 0 AND ab.imaPartID NOT LIKE 'ZBL%' ) as ca )
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MyData OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: I think the part you are adding contains a `)` but I see no matching `(`

Comment: I did add them,  The opening parentheses just before each Select statement is supposed to be that opening parenthesis, unless I misplaced them?

Comment: Ah, OK.  I was just looking at the little code for `AS aa`, if that is simply pasted in I _think_ you'd have a mismatch paran.  It's hard to test out since we don't have the db scheme and data to try it on.

Comment: Is the logic correct though?  I should be able to just add the left outer join the way I did, correct?  I don't see why it would give the syntax error.

Comment: It's hard to tell.  That's a lot of SQL code up there.  It's best if you can narrow down all the code to a Minimal Viable Example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Is having all those nested casts causing a problem? probably not, strip that out.  Get the SQL statement as small as possible and I bet in the process of doing so to update the code in question, you'll find the problem.

Comment: ok.  Thanks.  I'll see what I can manage.

Comment: I have shrunk it down to bare minimum, and it still gives the error:     SELECT aa.imaMethodID 
                   FROM M1_HB.dbo.AssemblyMaterialCombo
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN M1_HB.dbo.PartOperations ON AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodID = PartOperations.imoMethodID
                   AND AssemblyMaterialCombo.imaMethodAssemblyID = PartOperations.imoMethodAssemblyID AS aa
                WHERE ((aa.imaMethodRevisionID='')
                       AND (aa.imaParentAssemblyID = 0)
                       AND (aa.imaMethodID='1BC10200')

Comment: It seems Left outer joins is not allowed in CTE recursive queries... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.    Is there a way to accomplish what I need done?

Comment: wow! You should post that as your own answer.  I never knew that.

Comment: I edited my original post with more information... can anyone assist?  I am not an Sql expert by far,.

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong. `(Select <columns> FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON <conditions> AS aa) WHERE...` is nonsense and won't run anyway

Comment: Stick a `SELECT *` and then maybe it will make some sense. It's still a superfluous subquery, but at least it's logically and syntactically correct at that point.

Comment: Cancel that. It will still be incorrect as `aa` would be out of context in the subquery. It's sort of a mess, op. It's as if you've never written a query with a join in it before (which is fine, but surprising that the first time you would use it would be in a recursive statement).

Comment: I hadn't written a recursive query with a join it before... that was was confusing me... but I figured it out.  Thanks.

Comment: I figured out that you can't have outer joins with CTE recursives...